# Default Android app crashes on AVD running anything less than Lollipop

Tags: android

I seem to be having a bit of an issue getting an app to run on an AVD that is running anything less than Lollipop. I set the minimum SDK to Jellybean (4.2) yet whenever I try to run it on an AVD with either Jellybean or Kit Kat, it crashes.

I've seen other people here having this issue and it could be resolved with multidex but I am having this issue even with applications that only consist of the default "Hello world" content when you first create a blank activity.

I created a demo project with a blank activity and changed absolutely nothing to it, yet it still crashes.

This is the error code it gives:

```
07-20 22:17:44.161 2698-2698/com.demo.demo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                             Process: com.demo.demo, PID: 2698
                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.demo.demo/com.demo.demo.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020013
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                              Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020013
                                                                 at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2101)
                                                                 at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:700)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:354)
                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:193)
                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:181)
                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:689)
                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:186)
                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:77)
                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:83)
                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:28)
                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:41)
                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:193)
                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:173)
                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:511)
                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71)
                                                                 at com.demo.demo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:10)
                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                              Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17: invalid drawable tag vector
                                                                 at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:933)
                                                                 at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
                                                                 at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2097)
                                                                 at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:700) 
                                                                 at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:354) 
                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:193) 
                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:181) 
                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:689) 
                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:186) 
                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:77) 
                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:83) 
                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146) 
                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:28) 
                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:41) 
                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:193) 
                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:173) 
                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:511) 
                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71) 
                                                                 at com.demo.demo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:10) 
                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Looking at it I thought that it might be an issue with the theme of the app but changing that doesn't change anything. I'm very new to Android so I'm just a bit unsure of what this could be.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I should probably also add that I'm using Android Studio in case that makes a difference.

Comment: What version of AppCompat are you using?

Comment: Sorry, like I mentioned, I'm very new to Android dev. The only place I've really heard of AppCompat is to do with the theme. Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: There should be a `build.gradle` file, generally in the `app` directory if you're using a project built off the default 'New Project' template. That should have a line labeled `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'` - what is that number at the end?

Comment: It's com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Add to you Gradle within the  defaultConfig

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

Also make sure your Activity extends AppCompatActivity, and not plain Activity.

Comment: Just added that line to Gradle. Checked and the Activity extends AppCompatActivity anyway. 

Getting what appears to be the same error.

Comment: Are you using Gradle 2.x or 1.5

Comment: If you are using Gradle 1.5 than you should rather use // Gradle Plugin 1.5 android { defaultConfig { generatedDensities = [] } // This is handled for you by the 2.0+ Gradle Plugin aaptOptions { additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors" } }

Comment: It's version 2.1.2 I think

Comment: Thinking maybe I should just uninstall and reinstall android studio

Comment: I just tried this on my laptop under the exact same conditions and it worked fine. Going to try reinstalling android studio.

Comment: Well that seemed to work. Guess I'll chalk it up to one of natures mysteries.